# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (1,80)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, reshape

While fitting cnn model to my data, it caught error:

```
    161         X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1],1])
    162         X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:]
--> 163         X_train_2 = X[:,10080:10160,:].reshape(1,80)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (1,80)
```

The input data consists of `X_train_1`(each sample of shape 1, 10080) and `X_train_2`(each sample of shape 1, 80). `X_train_1` and `X_train_2` join to form a sample size of shape `1, 10160`. What is the `size 3` referring to?

Comment: Looks like all your variables have 3 dimensions. Is it `reshape(1,80,1)` that you want?

Comment: Hi @konstanze, yes, it would contribute to the second part of a sample, which is a time series of shape (1, 10160).

Comment: What is the actual shape of the original `X`? you would get exactly this error if `X` was shape (1, 10083, 1) not the (1, 10160, 1) that you assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following with the two different values for `n`:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10160
#n = 10083
X = np.arange(n).reshape(1,-1)
np.shape(X)

X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1],1])
X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:]
X_train_2 = X[:,10080:10160,:].reshape(1,80)
np.shape(X_train_2)
```

If you cannot make sure that `X` is 10160 long I suggest one of the following solutions:

`X_train_1` with 10080 samples, `X_train_2` with the rest:

```
X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1],1])
X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:] # X_train_1 with 10080 samples
X_train_2 = X[:,10080:,:].reshape(1,-1) # X_train_2 with the remaining samples
```

Or `X_train_2` with 80 samples, `X_train_1` with the rest:

```
X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1],1])
X_train_1 = X[:,0:-80,:] # X_train_1 with the remaining samples
X_train_2 = X[:,-80:,:].reshape(1,80) # X_train_2 with 80 samples
```